# Calling a func in other swift file which works with web-service returns nothing

Tags: ios, swift, web-services

In swift 2 When I'm communicating with a web-service and when I write these codes in button action it works fine.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in })

    alert.addAction(ok);

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.myaddress.com/web-service/iostest.aspx")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var postString = String();
    postString = "uid=1";
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {

            alert.title="Error"
            alert.message = "Connection error"

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            alert.title="Error"
            alert.message = "Server error"

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        alert.title="Info"
        alert.message = responseString as? String

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

As I said this works fine but as I want to do this from different ViewControls as well I have created a swift file which contains a struct and a static func in that struct that returns the the "responseString" so I could alert it in the view control. Something like this:

```
struct globalClass {

static func sendInfo(url: String, data: String) -> (answer: String, errorCode: Int32) {
    var res = String();
    var err = Int32();
    err = 0;
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    let postString: String = data;
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            err = 1;
            return;
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            err = 2;
            return;
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        res = (responseString as? String)!;
    }
    task.resume();
    return (res, err);
}
```

But now when I call this func from my button it shows me an empty alert very fast that it seems like it didn't get anything from web-service and didn't even try too.

I put these in the button action:

```
@IBAction func btnData(sender: AnyObject) {

    let y: String = "uid=1";

    let res = globalClass.sendInfo("http://www.myaddress.com/web-service/iostest.aspx", data: y);

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert);
    let OK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil);
    alert.addAction(OK);

    if (res.errorCode==0) {
        alert.title = "Info";
        alert.message = res.answer;
    } else if (res.errorCode==1) {
        alert.title = "Error";
        alert.message = "Error connecting to server";
    } else {
        alert.title = "Error";
        alert.message = "Server returned an error";
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);
    };

}
```

Thanks for the help,

Afshin Mobayen Khiabani

Comment: `globalClass.sendInfo` uses async call, but is used like a sync method. Try to deliver the result using closure instead of ret value of sendInfo

Comment: Thank you but how :D I'll try to find how but can you elaborate  on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`globalClass.sendInfo` uses async call - `dataTaskWithRequest`. The result of the request will be delivered in completion of this method. But you don't wait for that result, instead you try to use `sendInfo` like a sync function.

To be able to deliver the result from `dataTaskWithRequest`'s completion, put your own completion into `sendInfo` and invoke this completion (closure) when the result is delivered. An example

```
struct GlobalClass {
    static func sendInfo(url: String, data: String, completion: (answer: String?, errorCode: Int32?) -> Void) {
        // you code here which prepares request
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            // you parse the result here
            // you deliver the result using closure
            completion(string, error)
        }
        task.resume();
    }
}
```

And an example of usage:

```
func usage() {
    GlobalClass.sendInfo("url", data: "data") { (answer, errorCode) in
        // your answer and errorCode here
        // handle the result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static func sendInfo(url: String, data: String, completion: (answer: String, errorCode: Int32) -> ()){
//Your code..

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        res = (responseString as? String)!;
     completion(answer: res, errorCode: err)
    }
    task.resume()



}
```

Then when you call the `sendInfo`, call like so:

```
sendInfo(url: "your url", data: "your data") { (result, error) in

//you use your result and error values as u want.
}
```

Comment: Thank you but completion(answer: res, errorCode: err) should written before ask.resume()